# Introduce setter for some - but not all - inherited classes

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, properties, overriding

I am having a hard time implementing a property in C# that only has a **getter** in the abstract base class, but where I need to introduce a **setter** in one of the derived classes.

---

### Update: For a shorter explanation of a generalized example of this question, [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489361/override-abstract-readonly-property-to-read-write-property). The selected answer has explained why this is currently impossible to do in C#, however, in my mind no satisfactory solution has yet been provided.

---

An overview of my class diagram is shown below:

[image: Class diagram]

My objective is that the two classes **TextElementStatic** and **TextElementReferenceSource** should have a **Text** property with both getters and setters, while the class **TextElementReferenceTarget** should have a **Text** property with only a getter. I'm constantly using **ITextElement** while referencing all of these objects, and I need to ensure that the **ITextElement** interface only has a getter. Also, the base class **TextElement** implements a lot of common code, so all classes need to inherit from that class.

My current code looks like this:

*Interface: ITextElement*

```
public interface ITextElement
{
    string Text { get; }
}
```

*Interface: ITextElementUpdatable*

```
public interface ITextElementUpdatable : ITextElement
{
    new string Text { get; set; }
}
```

*Abstract class: TextElement* **(This is where my problem is, explained below)**

```
public abstract class TextElement : ITextElement
{
    // I want to mark this 'abstract', but that causes my problem
    public virtual string Text
    {
        get
        {
            // NOTE: This should never be called
            Debug.Fail("Called virtual Text getter that should never be called");
            return default(string);
        }
    }
}
```

*Abstract class: TextElementUpdatable*

```
public abstract class TextElementUpdatable : TextElement, ITextElementUpdatable
{
    // Should have both a getter and a setter  
    public new virtual string Text { get; set; }
}
```

*Class: TextElementStatic*

```
public class TextElementStatic : TextElementUpdatable
{
    // Should have both a getter and a setter
    // No Text property declaration
    // Inherits Text property from TextElementUpdatable
}
```

*Class: TextElementReferenceSource*

```
public class TextElementReferenceSource : TextElementUpdatable
{      
    // Should have both a getter and a setter     
    public override string Text
    {
        get { return _internalobject.Text; }
        set { _internalobject.Text = value; }
    }
}
```

*Class: TextElementReferenceTarget*

```
public class TextElementReferenceTarget : TextElement
{
    // Should ONLY have a getter
    public override string Text
    {
        get { return _internalobject.Text; }
    }
}
```

So, my issue is: I really want to declare the Text property in the base class TextElement abstract, because it should always be implemented in the derived classes (both TextElementUpdatable, TextElementReferenceSource and TextElementReferenceTarget implements this property). However, if I try to convert the property to `public abstract string Text { get; }`, then I receive an error in **TextElementUpdatable** specifying that

```
TextElementUpdatable.Text hides the inherited property TextElement.Text
```

Further, if I change the property in **TextElementUpdatable** from `new` to `override` the error message is replaced by:

```
Cannot override because TextElement.Text does not have an overridable set accessor
```

Now, I could go back to **TextElement** and change the property to `public virtual string Text { get; private set; }` and call it a day, since that method should never be called anyway (which is basically the solution I have now). However, if I or someone create another derived class later on, I want to force me/them to implement the Text-property, hence I would rather mark it abstract than provide a virtual implementation.

**Any suggestions on how I can do this the right way - even if it should involve a lot of refactoring?**

I know that I could separate the two objectives her, providing one inherited **Text** property with only a getter, and then introduce a `SetText()` method in the **ITextElementUpdatable** interface. However, I'm wondering whether it is possible to find a good solution with properties only.

---

Another similar question, but without any answers I've been able to use: [C# - What should I do when every inherited class needs getter from base class, but setter only for ONE inherited class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965410/c-sharp-what-should-i-do-when-every-inherited-class-needs-getter-from-base-cla)

Comment: +1 for an *extremely* well explained and written question. Unfortunately, I don't think I have a good answer for you, it looks to me like you have found the best/only work around. The best of luck to you though!

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489361/override-abstract-readonly-property-to-read-write-property) help?

Comment: @WilliamBarbosa Thanks, I didn't find that one during my research. It looks like the same issue. I'm not particularly happy with the answer though, as it looks like too much of a hack to me. Then I'll rather use the `SetProperty()` solution as I find that cleaner - unless anyone can provide a different answer..

Answer (score 1):

It is really an exciting desing problem, but.. You have to use the new keyword what is not a good practice. Try to avoid them.
Of course, property names can be the same in the interfaces, but if both implemented by a class (and one of the props defined without a setter), we have to implement them explicitelly. We have to accept that these properties "conflict".
You could introduce abstract methods:

```
public abstract class TextElement : ITextElement
{
    public string Text { get { return GetText(); } }

    protected abstract string GetText();
}

public abstract class TextElementUpdatable : TextElement, ITextElementUpdatable
{
    string ITextElementUpdatable.Text
    {
        get { return GetText(); }
        set { SetText(value); }
    }

    protected abstract void SetText(string text);
}
```

Comment: +1 for a nice answer, however, in my mind it does not satisfy the intent of the question to do this with properties *only*. If I'm implementing protected SetText() methods and have to introduce colliding properties, I think it is cleaner from a design perspective to just offer a public SetText() and keep the property as a getter only, as discussed in the question. A similar approach to yours can be found in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1489383/521773

Answer (score 0):

It can be a bit confusing that you use the same property in your hierarchy with different meanings. Maybe the implementation of ITextElement.get_Text and ITextElementUpdatable.get_Text will diverge later - the interfaces define two independent behavior, and we do not use basic types all the time, like string.
So my suggestion is that you should have a property in ITextElement for read only purpose, and another property in ITextElementUpdatable with different name. In this manner, your methods can be defined as abstract, of course.

Comment: Well, it is not really to different properties with different meanings. It is rather a property which in some derived classes is read-only, and in some it is read-write. I'm not sure I agree with you on the confusion in this specific situation.